# what the problem I am facing is this site at once I am opening its redirecting towards some advertisement

Tags: discussion

This is not a math related question but what the problem I am facing is this site at once I am opening its redirecting towards some advertisement and I can't even control it. So this disturbs me in doing mathstack. So what should I do??

Comment: I suggest installing some malware-removal software and running it. If your computer is completely compromised there's not much you can do besides doing a clean reinstall, though.

Comment: I doubt this is related to this site specifically. Is this the only site where you experience this problem?

Comment: Yes thats why I am worried..